# Cannot load properties from JBboss' standalone\configuration folder

Tags: spring, properties, configuration, jboss

I am migrating an application from Websphere to JBoss 6.3. We use to pick some values from environment variable in IBM WebSphere, whereas in JBoss I have added this values in a properties file and kept in folder `<jboss_install>\standalone\configuration`.

And have updated the file location in Program argument like: `-DenvironmentDir=C:/jboss-eap-6.3/standalone/configuration/Environment.properties`

The values defined in `Environment` file are then looked up using Spring Framework configuration:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${environmentDir}" />

<bean id="tibConnectionFactory"     class="com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory">
<property name="serverUrl"><value>${OE.MESSAGING.SERVER.URL}</value>         </property>
<property name="userName">  <value>${${app.cfg}.${app}.${jms.provider}.username}</value></property> 
<property name="userPassword">  <value>${${app.cfg}.${app}.${jms.provider}.password}</value></property>
</bean>
```

But when I start the server I get following exception:

```
14:31:31,764 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'tibConnectionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/config/spring-jms.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'OE.MESSAGING.SERVER.URL' in string value "${OE.MESSAGING.SERVER.URL}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'OE.MESSAGING.SERVER.URL' in string value "${OE.MESSAGING.SERVER.URL}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:211) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:180) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:155) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) [spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:161) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:59) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:94) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'OE.MESSAGING.SERVER.URL' in string value "${OE.MESSAGING.SERVER.URL}"
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can you try: `<... location="classpath:${environmentDir}/Environment.properties" />`? And eventually change the `-D` setting to `-DenvironmentDir=C:/jboss-eap-6.3/standalone/configuration`

Comment: Thanks for your response I tried this by adding the location in applicationContext and -D setting in Jboss server Program arguments as well as in standalone.conf.bat  but didn't worked